# Universal property of blowups for diagonal embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

Corollary 7.15 of Hartshorne states: If $f:Y\to X$ is a morphism of Noetherian schemes and $\mathcal{I}$ is a coherent sheaf of ideals on $X$, then there is a diagram 
$$
\begin{align*}
&\overline{Y}&&  \to &&\overline{X}\\
&\downarrow&&&&\downarrow\\
&Y&&\to&&X
\end{align*}
$$
where $\overline{X}$ is the blowup of $X$ along $\mathcal{I}$ and $\overline{Y}$ is the blowup of $Y$ along $f^{-1}\mathcal{I}\cdot \mathcal{O}_Y$.

I would like to apply this to a complex variety $V$ as follows: given two integers $1\leq n\leq m$, consider the map on product spaces defined by 
$$f:V^n\to V^m, (a_1,\dots,a_n)\to (a_1,\dots,a_n,a_n,\dots,a_n).$$
Now if $n\geq 2$ it seems that restricting the ideal sheaf of the small diagonal $\Delta_m\subset V^m$ gives me the ideal sheaf of the small diagonal $\Delta_n\subset V^n$, and hence we have a corresponding map

$$
\begin{align*}
&\text{Bl}_{\Delta_n}V^n&&  \to &&\text{Bl}_{\Delta_m}V^m\\
&\downarrow&&&&\downarrow\\
&V^n&&\to&&V^m
\end{align*}
$$
But if $n=1$, I am slightly confused as to what should go into the top left corner. It seems like there should be a copy of $V$ blown up along the zero ideal, but I don't know how to make sense of that. Given that the blowup should be a  copy of $\text{Proj}(\oplus I^n)$, I believe there should be a copy of $V$ in the top left corner. But then I am confused with what the map $V\to \text{Bl}_{\Delta_m}V^m$ would be; since the diagram commutes I would expect $V$ to map into the exceptional divisor of $\text{Bl}_{\Delta_m}V^m$ but this should require the tangent bundle of $V$ to have a global section, which shouldn't always hold.

Could anyone shed some light as to if this reasoning is correct, and if so, what is the map $V\to \text{Bl}_{\Delta_m}V^m$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The blowup along the zero ideal should be zero. For example consider the graded ring $A$, which has $A$ in degree 0 and all the rest are zero. This set $Proj(A)$ is empty by definition, since there are no ideals that donot contain all of the positively graded part of the ring.